# cloudera vm oozieWorkflow java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hue

I'm new to Hadoop and I have the flowing problem:

I keep getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when I’m trying to run my oozzie work flow. I use the Cloudera quick start VM v 4.5.

used oozzie settings:

- Jar name : sample.jar
- Main class : Driver
- Arguments : in_single/ out

used java class

```
public class Driver{
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>
{
    @Override
    public void map(final Object key, final Text value, final Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        context.write(new Text("key " + UUID.randomUUID().toString()), new Text("value " + UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
    private final IntWritable   result  = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    public void reduce(final Text key, final Iterable<Text> values, final Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        for (Text value : values)
            context.write(new Text(UUID.randomUUID().toString()), new Text(value));
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2)
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    Job job = new Job(conf, "MRJ");
    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}}
```

used pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>LittleBigData.Sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>WordCountCeSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.92.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Anyone knows why this is, and how I can solve this error?

added:
stdout log

```
Oozie Launcher starts

Heart beat

Starting the execution of prepare actions
Completed the execution of prepare actions successfully

Files in current dir:/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/.
======================
File: action.xml
File: .action.xml.crc
Dir: tmp

Oozie Java/Map-Reduce/Pig action launcher-job configuration
=================================================================
Workflow job id   : 0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W
Workflow action id: 0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W@MRJ

Classpath         :
------------------------
/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/10-mapreduce-TASKTRACKER
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/lib/tools.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hue-plugins-2.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/event-publish-4.7.2-shaded.jar
/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/tt-instrumentation-4.7.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/navigator-plugin-4.7.2-shaded.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-tests.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-auth.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations.jar
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-tests.jar
/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-1860118727254658637_-1076703533_1494062849/localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W/MRJ--java/java-launcher.jar
/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-2689018396186434637_1026166682_1483994242/localhost.localdomain/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_cloudera_-oozie-32-1390902497.72/lib/hadoop-examples.jar
/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/7324599977783858114_-844170377_413593709/localhost.localdomain/user/oozie/share/lib/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar
/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/1983218835533269135_-24009080_413593767/localhost.localdomain/user/oozie/share/lib/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-3.3.2-cdh4.4.0.jar
/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work
------------------------

Main class        : Driver

Maximum output    : 2048

Arguments         :
in_single/
out

Java System Properties:
------------------------
#
#Tue Jan 28 05:33:17 PST 2014
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
hadoop.tasklog.taskid=attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0
oozie.action.externalChildIDs.properties=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/externalChildIds.properties
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/amd64
java.vm.version=20.7-b02
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,TLA
java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url=http\://java.sun.com/
path.separator=\:
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
user.country=US
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_32-b05
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch=amd64
oozie.job.id=0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W
oozie.action.id=0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W@MRJ
java.io.tmpdir=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/tmp
line.separator=\n
oozie.action.output.properties=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/output.properties
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=0
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
os.name=Linux
log4j.configuration=task-log4j.properties
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work
oozie.action.conf.xml=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/action.xml
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=50.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
user.home=/usr/lib/hadoop
user.timezone=America/Los_Angeles
java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob
file.encoding=UTF-8
java.specification.version=1.6
java.class.path=/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/10-mapreduce-TASKTRACKER\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/lib/tools.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hue-plugins-2.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar\:/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/event-publish-4.7.2-shaded.jar\:/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/tt-instrumentation-4.7.2.jar\:/usr/share/cmf/lib/plugins/navigator-plugin-4.7.2-shaded.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-tests.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.5.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-auth.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations.jar\:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-tests.jar\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-1860118727254658637_-1076703533_1494062849/localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000039-140127061714030-oozie-oozi-W/MRJ--java/java-launcher.jar\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-2689018396186434637_1026166682_1483994242/localhost.localdomain/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_cloudera_-oozie-32-1390902497.72/lib/hadoop-examples.jar\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/7324599977783858114_-844170377_413593709/localhost.localdomain/user/oozie/share/lib/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/1983218835533269135_-24009080_413593767/localhost.localdomain/user/oozie/share/lib/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-3.3.2-cdh4.4.0.jar\:/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work
user.name=mapred
hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
oozie.action.newId.properties=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/newId.properties
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
sun.java.command=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child 127.0.0.1 46136 attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0 /var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/userlogs/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0 -17914583
java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre
sun.arch.data.model=64
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
hadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.6.0_32
java.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext\:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/resources.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/rt.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jsse.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jce.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/charsets.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar\:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/classes
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
file.separator=/
oozie.launcher.job.id=job_201401270439_0058
oozie.action.stats.properties=/mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201401270439_0058/attempt_201401270439_0058_m_000000_0/work/stats.properties
java.vendor.url.bug=http\://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=
------------------------

=================================================================

>>> Invoking Main class now >>>


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [Driver], exception invoking main(), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Driver not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Driver not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1617)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:493)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Driver not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1523)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1615)
... 9 more

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully


Oozie Launcher ends
```

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue - the stack trace would help.

Comment: i've added the stdout log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add all the dependent jars in a 'lib' folder in the workspace of the workflow?

Comment: I'll try it, bud I just use the normal Hadoop dependencies and regular Java functions. I used a wourdcount sample as a template for the driver, I copy paste the sample and chanced the code. The weirdest thing is, if I name the class 'WourdCount', it gives no error's. Bud when I name the class 'Driver' I get an error.

Comment: If I use the job designer instead of the oozie work flow editor it solves this problem. Thanks for the advice, it lead me to try the job designer. 

Only now I get an “Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 “ :(